# Non Transactional attribute uniqness in Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have app where a user can have multiple accounts. We store the data in Dynamodb, and the table is as follows:

```
partitionKey: userId
sortKey: accountId
info: someAccountInfo
```

Now we need to set one of the accounts as "default". This action needs to be atomic, to prevent a race condition where 2 different accounts will be set as default, or non will.

If we'll add "isDefault" as an attribute, we'll need to make a transaction:

```
1. Get the current default account
2. unset the current default account
3. set it to the new default account
```

How can we achieve the same consistency without transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of storing the "default" flag at the account level, you should store it at the user level?  So, instead of...

```
PK     SK        Info...
User22 Account88 IsDefault Someinfo1 Someinfo2
User22 Account50 IsDefault Someinfo1 Someinfo2
User22 Account30 IsDefault Someinfo1 Someinfo2
```

...where only one of the three accounts could be default, add a new special sort key for identifying the default account:

```
PK     SK        Info...
User22 Account88 Someinfo1 Someinfo2
User22 Account50 Someinfo1 Someinfo2
User22 Account30 Someinfo1 Someinfo2
User22 DefaultAc Account50
```

Now when you want to change the default account, you update the "User22 - DefaultAc" item with the default account Id.  There can inherently be only one "User22 - DefaultAc" record, so even if two connected clients simultaneously update the default account, only one of them will stick.